# Formula - Picklists

Tags: formula-field

Im trying to create a formula field that will look at three other fields before updating with X Value.

For example - If 1st picklist value = X, 2nd picklist value = X and Amount = £XX - then update with X.

Any help here would be greatly appreicated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use if condition

```
 IF( Name  = 'X' &&  Active__c = 'TRUE' &&  Amount = 'Open' ,'XXX' , '')
```

replace Name with first picklist api name and Active__c with second picklist API name

multiple if conditions

```
IF(Amount = 10.00 && Term = 12 , 50,
    IF(Amount = 20.00 && Term = 24 ,100,
        200
    )
)
```

---

```
IF( CONTAINS(TEXT(How_is_the_order_funded__c),"Lease")&& Term_Number__c = 24 && Cost_per_Unit__c = 13.00 , 7.50,
    IF(CONTAINS(TEXT(How_is_the_order_funded__c),"Lease")&& Term_Number__c = 24 && Cost_per_Unit__c = 18.00, 12.50, 
       0) 
  )
```

Comment: I have gone with:

Comment: IF( CONTAINS(TEXT(How_is_the_order_funded__c),"Lease")&&  Term_Number__c = 12 &&  Cost_per_Unit__c  = 12.00 ,'XXX' , 7)

Comment: However im getting the error message:Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'IF()'. Expected Text, received Number

Comment: IF( CONTAINS(TEXT(How_is_the_order_funded__c),"Lease")&&  Term_Number__c = 12 && Cost_per_Unit__c  = 12.00 ,0.00, 7)  - This version seems to work (syntax ok) how ever If I wanted to add multiple variations in the same formula, for varied resultsa, how would I structure the formula? Thanks again.

Comment: I appreciate your help here but would you mind confirming.. To add an aditional 'IF' for a different result based on the same fields. How woul dI structure the formula..

Comment: Sorry Ratan, What Im trying to achieve isnt to add an extra field. What I need my result to be X if the values in the three fields used are X. So example one would be Amount = 10.00, Term = 12, Funded by = "Funder" return would be £50. Example two would be  Amount = 20.00, Term = 24, Funded by = "Funder" return would be £100. Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry Ratan, I appreciate you help but dont think you follow me. Neverver mind thanks anyway. appreciate the effot. I have many variations not just the two

Comment: Where does the 100, 200 come into it though...

Comment: Using This string, would you paste back how you would add anohter variation 
 
IF( CONTAINS(TEXT(How_is_the_order_funded__c),"Lease")&& Term_Number__c = 12 && Cost_per_Unit__c = 12.00 ,0.00, 7)

Comment: 1, IF( CONTAINS(TEXT(How_is_the_order_funded__c),"Lease")&& Term_Number__c = 24 && Cost_per_Unit__c = 13.00 ,7.50, 0)

Comment: 2, IF( CONTAINS(TEXT(How_is_the_order_funded__c),"Lease")&& Term_Number__c = 24 && Cost_per_Unit__c = 18.00 ,12.50, 0)

Comment: **IF( CONTAINS(TEXT(How_is_the_order_funded__c),"Lease")&& Term_Number__c = 24 && Cost_per_Unit__c = 13.00 , 7.50,
 IF(CONTAINS(TEXT(How_is_the_order_funded__c),"Lease")&& Term_Number__c = 24 && Cost_per_Unit__c = 18.00, 12.50, 0) 
  )**  I used 1 & 2 one

Comment: Great thanks for this. I tried the formula but got the error: Error: Compiled formula is too big to execute (5,457 characters). Maximum size is 5,000 characters

Comment: are you using any formula field in conditions?

Comment: Sorry can you expand on this question im not sure how to check this? Thank you

Comment: Two of the fields are formulas yes.

Comment: Term_Number__c and Cost_per_Unit__c correct ? if you dont mid can you please share these two field code here. may be we can merge here only

Comment: ? share the field code? The field names?

Comment: means formula field condition written in those formula fields (Term_Number__c and Cost_per_Unit__c)